# yeoman how to set headers (.htaccess?)

Tags: node.js, yeoman, gruntjs

Running  *yeoman server* does not seem to recognize the .htaccess file by default.  Is there an additional step to enable reading of the .htaccess file?

Here are the lines I have uncommented with no apparent affect in setting headers after restarting:

```
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Cross-domain AJAX requests
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Serve cross-domain Ajax requests, disabled by default.
    # enable-cors.org
    # code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
```

Or maybe the proper question is how would one set headers when running yeoman server?  Is there another option, perhaps in Gruntfile.js?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`grunt server` is just a Node.js [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) server and doesn't support .htaccess

Though since [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) supports custom middlewares you can add this to your Gruntfile.js:

```
var corsMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
}

grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        middleware: function(connect, options) {
          return [
            // Serve static files
            connect.static(options.base),
            // Make empty directories browsable
            connect.directory(options.base),
            // CORS support
            corsMiddleware
          ];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Any updates on Yeoman 1.0 and how to support Connect middleware?

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide a link or explain the options of the corsMiddleware and how to use it to mimic a traditional .htaccess file settings.. Especially for using it as a front end ajax mock api server

Comment: corsMiddlware is just a custom middleware I created for you. No options. Middlewares are simple proxies that lets you modify requests. In this example it just adds some headers. But you can do even more powerful things. I suggest you read up on Connect middlewares: https://google.com/search?q=connect+middleware

Comment: Is this added in the root Gruntfile.js or in the node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/Gruntfile.js? I have tried both, but no success. I am trying to connect to MongoHQ from my development machine.

Comment: It should be added to *your* Gruntfile.js (root).

Comment: It seems yeoman 1.0 support CORS "*". I run `grunt server` and without and config I can make requests to different domain.

Comment: I get `Warning: connect.static is not a function Use --force to continue`